# Code cleanup for Django queries and ternary operator

Tags: python-3.x, django

How best can I clean up this code into one Django query with the ternary operator :

```
if isinstance(self.instance, Business):
            agg_shares = BeneficialOwnerShares.objects.filter(
                parent_company=parent
            ).exclude(
                owner_company=self.instance
            ).aggregate(
                sum_shares=Coalesce(Sum('allocation_of_shares'), V(0))
            )
        else:
            agg_shares = BeneficialOwnerShares.objects.filter(
                parent_company=parent
            ).exclude(
                owner_person=self.instance
            ).aggregate(
                sum_shares=Coalesce(Sum('allocation_of_shares'), V(0))
            )
```

Am trying to add the ternary operator in the `exclude()` function to switch between the

`owner_person=self.instance` and  `owner_company=self.instance`, but it doesn't work , how best can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to work with a dictionary, and perform dictionary unpacking:

```
agg_shares = BeneficialOwnerShares.objects.filter(
    parent_company=parent
).exclude(
    **{'owner_company' if isinstance(self.instance, Business) else 'owner_person': self.instance}
).aggregate(
    sum_shares=Coalesce(Sum('allocation_of_shares'), V(0))
)
```

That being said, I would advice to write this with an extra line:

```
key = 'owner_company' if isinstance(self.instance, Business) else 'owner_person'

agg_shares = BeneficialOwnerShares.objects.filter(
    parent_company=parent
).exclude(
    **{key: self.instance}
).aggregate(
    sum_shares=Coalesce(Sum('allocation_of_shares'), V(0))
)
```

Comment: Thanks, Willem for the simplicity.